# What does it mean and how do you pronounce あっ?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

I saw someone talk about a 「はあっ」that they saw in a book, so I looked it up but didn't find much, just some words/sites that had あっ in them. (I couldn't read the rest) I was wondering how one might pronounce っ at the end of a word. I'm also not sure if っ can be applied after あ only, or other vowels/characters.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1457/9831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the term 学校 for example. This is equivalent to がっこう which is pronounced as *gakkou* meaning **school**.

Because of the small つ, namely っ, then the romaji is spelt with two letters. Since っ occurs before こ then the two letters in the romaji spelling would be k.

> > Thus, how must we pronounce the term はあっ if there is no letter following from っ?

It is a good question, and the answer is that we pronounce this as *ha* as opposed to *haa*.

*ha* has an abrupt ending off the *a* vowel (short vowel sound), and *haa* has a long vowel sound at the end. However, we could simply write は, right?

> Well, let's consider the following conversation:
>
> > "Hey, Jimmy! How are you to—"
> >
> > "Shut up, Tommy!"
>
> The person who spoke second had cut the first person speaking off. If we were to write this conversation in Japanese, instead of using the hyphon, —, we would use っ instead.

So if someone said 「は」then this would just show that one has said the statement *completely* and finished it off, without ever being cut off in the process. But, to show that someone was saying a sentence or a word that began with は but was abruptly cut off, we show this by writing「はっ」instead.

But because it is written as 「は**あ**っ」 with the letter あ, then this shows that whoever was speaking and was cut off, he/she was going to say a word (or begin a sentence) that began with はあ in particular.

---

Go [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/what-does-the-little-%E3%81%A3-tsu-signify-when-at-the-end-of-a-word?noredirect=1&lq=1) for another reference. The comment below your post has also provided the same link.

Comment: I thought you would use ーー to show an abrupt end to a sentence?

Comment: @Sweeper you did? How were you taught? I emailed my Japanese teacher before posting this answer in order to confirm...

Comment: "Hey, Jimmy! How are you to—" "Shut up, Tommy!" みたいなのが日本語では「おい、ジミー！お前どうやってーー」「黙れトミー！」じゃなくて「おい、ジミー！お前どうやって**っ** 」「黙れトミー！」になる、ってこと・・？？　それはないわー

Comment: @Chocolate So... it is not? It seems as if my teacher is wrong with many things. I hardly believe this being the case, from the perspective of being his student for nearly two years.

Comment: @Sweeper Last time I remember using a hyphen "ー", it was to *elongate* vowels (in katakana).

Comment: @user477343 I know it's confusing because they look similar, but the long vowel marker `ー` and dash `―` are two different things.  Neither of them is a hyphen `-`.  Anyway, if you read much Japanese, you'll come across lots of examples like the one Chocolate has given.

Answer (score 3):

When っ is at the end of a word, it indicates a glottal stop or a “choked sound” according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3). Imagine that you suddenly remembered something and went “Ah!—” That would be close to how あっ would sound.

Comment: If you are pronouncing 「あっ」 like "Ah!", then you are pronouncing it incorrectly.

Comment: I know how to pronounce 「あっ」, though perhaps the way that “Ah!—” sounds in my mind differs from how it sounds in yours.