# How would I indicate yelling when writing Japanese?

Tags: typesetting

In English typing in capital letters is considered yelling. How would I indicate yelling when writing in Japanese?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

長音符や小さい「っ」、それから感嘆符をたくさん付ければつけるほど、叫んでいるように見えるぞ**おおぉぉぉぉぉぉーーーーーーっっっ！！！**

具体的な例を知りたいなら、色んなマンガを読んでみるんだ**ああああああぁぁぁぁ〰️〰️〰️〰️〰️〰️〰️ッッッ！！！！！**

[image]

---

Seriously, try taking a look at some light novel, or a shōnen manga such as *Dragon Ball* or *One Piece*. You can use one or more of:

- exclamation mark
- long vowel marker (ー) or wavy dash (〰️)
- small vowels (ぁぃぅぇぉ)
- small tsu

They can be stacked (e.g., `っっっ`, `!!!!!`).

Related:

- [What does the little っ (tsu) signify when at the end of a word?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1457/5010)