# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: meaning, katakana, anime, symbols, japanese-to-english

Can anyone please let me know what this is supposed to mean? I heard that it’s a sound effect or sfx like Japanese symbol, but I’m not sure. Thank you! [image]

Comment: Isn't there another katakana on the left? I can vaguely see red pixels at the top-left corner of the picture you pasted...

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it so hopefully you could answer my question with the better looking picture. I’m mainly concerned about what the symbols mean on the right.

Answer (score 3):

It's three distorted small-tsu's in katakana (`ッッッ`), which is like `!!!`.

Related:

- [What does the little っ (tsu) signify when at the end of a word?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1457/5010)
- [How would I indicate yelling when writing Japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69948/5010)

Answer (score 2):

It's "ブワアッッッ"

> I heard that it’s a sound effect or sfx like Japanese symbol, but I’m not sure.

Yes, ブワッ is a sound effect for something spreading, exploding, overflowing, etc.
Additional ア and ッ just strengthen it.
In this case, it represents his blood spouting out.

ブワッ is a very common sound effect and used in various way.
Translation list below would help you.
http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/browse/buwa/

Comment: Um, I asked OP to add the whole text (because I wanted to be 100% certain that it was `ッ`), but OP wants to know specifically about [this part](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/77156/1)...

Answer (score -1):

Just to elaborate a little more on what's already been said, the small tsu (ツ or つ) extend the sound of the preceding syllable or add emphasis. So in this case it's basically turning the buwaa (ブワア) into something more like buwaaaaaaaaa! (ブワアッッッ).