# Why the つ after あのね？

Tags: grammar, manga, orthography

[image]

What's the contrasting action over here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the little っ (tsu) signify when at the end of a word?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/what-does-the-little-%e3%81%a3-tsu-signify-when-at-the-end-of-a-word)

Comment: "What's the contrasting action over here?" - sorry, I can't understand the underlying thought process. Why do you expect that there should be any "contrasting action", and what would that have to do with the utterance?

Answer (score 3):

That's a small tsu (i.e. っ) and not a つ, and as such represents a glottal stop. In context, this probably indicates that the utterance was cut off suddenly -- after all, the character looks to be embarrassed or flustered.